# What Does Shifting Variables OR REGISTERS means ? 1<<REGISTER_ADDRESS

Tags: operators, bit-manipulation, shift

I have learned about shift left and shift right registers in bitwise operators. But i am confused with below code. 
RX_DR shifted ? what does that mean ? this is just random example i just need to know meaning of it.

```
nrf24_configRegister(STATUS,(1<<RX_DR)|(1<<TX_DS)|(1<<MAX_RT));
```

Please help.

Comment: Can't help until we know _why_ you are confused. You say you understand shifts, so what is the problem? Specify what happens that you didn't expect, and we can tell you why that expectation is ill-founded.

Comment: I mean to say 1<<RX_DR, i have seen examples stating b = 01101110, where a = b << 1, means it will left shit by 1 giving a = 11011100. So i was confused 1 << RX_DR means ? 1 will be shifted into RX_DR ?

Comment: No, why would the meaning of `<<` suddenly change? `1 << RX_DR` results in `1` shifted left by the amount in `RX_DR`. It's just a use of a variable in a calculation, like any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these constants are the bit numbers of various flags in a register. Looking at [`nRF24L01.h`](http://maniacbug.github.io/RF24/nRF24L01_8h_source.html) leads me to believe their values are:

```
#define RX_DR  6
#define TX_DS  5
#define MAX_RT 4
```

This corresponds to a bit layout like:

```
                TX_DS
                v 
(bit #) 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0
            ^       ^
(flag)      RX_DR   MAX_RT
```

Here I've labeled a few of the bits in an 8-bit register. Bit 6 is the RX_DR flag, bit 5 is the TX_DS flag, and bit 4 is the MAX_RT flag.

```
(1<<RX_DR)|(1<<TX_DS)|(1<<MAX_RT)
```

This bit of code constructs a register value where those three bits are set and the rest are unset. How does it do that? Consider `1<<TX_DS`. This takes the value `1` (binary `00000001`) and shifts it left 5 places, yielding `32` (binary `00100000`).

That value is bitwise ORed (`|`) with the other two flags. ORing numbers together combines their 1 bits, yielding a value where all of the 1 bits from each operand are set.

```
1<<RX_DR  == 1<<6 == 01000000 in binary
1<<TX_DS  == 1<<5 == 00100000 in binary
1<<MAX_RT == 1<<4 == 00010000 in binary
```

ORing `1<<RX_DR` and `1<<TX_DS` and `1<<MAX_RT` together gives the value `112`, or in binary:

```
01110000
```

See how that binary value has bits 6, 5, and 4 set?